# Enable and Disble Listview with Some Condition in Android

Tags: android, listview, isenabled

How to enable all the items in listview when check box is selected and disabled when check box is unchecked.I have used

```
if(checkbox.isChecked)
{
listview.setEnabled(false)
listview.setClickable(false)
}
else
{
listview.setEnabled(true)
listview.setClickable(true)
}
```

But it is not working.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if(yourcheckbox.isChecked()){
     yourlistview.setClickable(true);} 
 else{
      yourlistview.setClickable(false);}
```

You can run this as a background process, in a separate thread so it keeps getting checked, whether the checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: How to run this as a background process.Can you please explain briefly.

Comment: I suggest creating a Thread. With in the thread's run method create a while loop, which will be always true, and keeps on checking these conditions. You can use break to get out of the loop any time, and destroy the thread. By the way, just saw the edit now, you need to know that the method 'isChecked()' returns true if it is checked. You are doing it the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

you can use OncheckedChangeListener method of Checkbox class

```
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked)
                {
                    listview.setEnabled(false)
                    listview.setClickable(false)
                }
                else
                {
                    listview.setEnabled(true)
                    listview.setClickable(true)
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response.I have already tried this.It is not working.